# My Cisco phones are getting registered to other call manager

Tags: voip, cisco

i have one subscriber and one publisher , when i am trying to register my phone to the subscriber , it is always getting registered to publisher only, i have tried to reset the phones, deleting the ctl and itl files

Answer (score 0):

Look at CallManager groups configuration. A Cisco CallManager group specifies a prioritized list of up to three Cisco CallManagers. The first Cisco CallManager in the list serves as the primary Cisco CallManager for that group, and the other members of the group serve as secondary and tertiary (backup) Cisco CallManagers.

Comment: i have kept that as a default value only

Comment: i have given the correct sequence still it is registering to the publisher only

Comment: Check for CallManager service is running on your subscriber.

Comment: All the services are running fine